# Android views from .xml to .java - dependencies

Tags: java, android, xml, dependencies, parameters

I just worked a little on an application just to train. Fast I noticed .xml created views have an influence on performance so I decided to code them in the activties.
But I dont know how to set up all these params and dependcies, do I really need to create tons of params? This is how my .xml looks like:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:background="#000000"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/df_link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/df_link"
        android:onClick="openWebURL"
        android:contentDescription="@string/df_link" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/header" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mm_bottom_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/new_b"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="startNewGame"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/new_b" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/load_b"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="@string/load_b" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/options_b"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="@string/options_b" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dev_b"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="loadDevInfo"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/dev_b" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/wiki_b"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="showWiki"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/wiki_b" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to write a lot of code. That's why xml layouts are used instead. 
 [This](http://mainerrors.blogspot.in/2011/02/programmatically-creating-layout-part-1.html) should help.